# I tried using JSR223 assertion to find the missing elements after comparing them in JMeter. but I am geting an error

Tags: json, jmeter, web-api-testing

The data I have as such:(this is extracted from some get api respsonse)

id1:{abc,qwe,ert,yup,iop,bnm,dff} and so on

id2 :{qwe,ert,iop,bnm,dff}

I want to find the missing elements between them
So as suggested I have used JSR223 assertion and the groovy code is as follows:

log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id1_ALL'))

log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id2_ALL'))

def id1 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id1_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def id2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id2_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def missing = org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.disjunction(id1, id2)

log.info('Missing values: ' +missing)

When I run the script I got "javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script1" error in view result tree

AND

In log viwer panel I can see the id1 and id2 contents but missing values isn't shown got this error

ERROR o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: Problem in JSR223 script: JSR223 Assertion
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script1
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSR223Assertion.getResult(JSR223Assertion.java:50) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:931) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]

Can anyone help on how to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

so make sure you copy pasted the below code accurately and there are no missing or extra symbols anywhere:

```
log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id1_ALL'))

log.info('id1: '+vars.get('id2_ALL'))

def id1 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id1_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def id2 = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBetween(vars.get('id2_ALL'), '{', '}').split(',').collect()

def missing = org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.disjunction(id1, id2)

log.info('Missing values: ' +missing)
```

More information:

- [CollectionUtils.disjunction()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-)
- [StringUtils.substringBetween()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: No still I am getting same error, is it because I have extracted the varibale that has integer data type?

Comment: If error is the same then you made a typo somewhere somehow or the values of the variables you're showing are different from the real ones, double check them using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Comment: I have extracted number values using json extractor instead of string and used the same above code, I am getting same errorerror